# Include in the class construct

Tags: php

I want to include file depends on a variable passed in the construct.

Lets say that I have this class:

```
class A
{

public function __construct($isDebug = false)
    {
      include_once ($isDebug ? "debug.php" : "prod.php");
    }

}
```

How do I make the include affect globaly the whole file?

Comment: You cannot include files in the class body.
In a file defining a class, you may only include files in a method body or outside the class body.

Comment: @Imaginaerum: The file is being included from the body of the `__construct` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class A
{
public $debug=false;
public function __construct($isDebug = false)
    {
      $this->debug = $isDebug;
    }

public function init() {
    include_once ($this->debug ? "debug.php" : "prod.php");
}

}

$a = new A(true);
$a->init();
```

I don't know about your app, but this method work... But include into class file is not the best solution. What contains your files ?